# Need help trying to loop my enemies after they have died

Tags: python

```
 while phealth > 0
     while choice !a:    
       if choice.lower() == "a":
            print('You attack the',name,"and do",pstrength,"damage!")
            if random.random() < crit_chance:
                print('You got a critical hit +5 more damage')
                mhealth = mhealth - pstrength - 5
                print(mhealth)
            else:
                mhealth = mhealth - pstrength
                penergy = penergy - pstrength
                print(mhealth)
            if penergy <= 0:
                print('You ran out of energy but thankfully the old man saved but you lost',random.randint(0, pcoins),'coins.')
                coins = 0
            if mhealth <= 0:
                print('You killed the enemy and gained 1 coin')
                pcoins = pcoins + 1
```

The code just keeps going. I would rather want it to reset at the beginning of the loop after the enemy has died.

This is not a full version of the code!!!

Comment: Maybe you should fix your syntax errors first.

Comment: You could print a reset message in the `if mhealth <= 0:` part of the code and reset the enemy's health there, assuming you only want the enemy to reset but the player health stays the same.

Answer (score -1):

As posted by @ewz93 the code needed a reset message at the end!